# No me ejecuta la acción de insertar data de una tabla a otra

Tags: laravel-5

```
public function index(Contrato $contrato)
{
    return DB::select("SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM clausulas AS c, contrato_clausulas AS cc WHERE cc.contrato_id='".$contrato->id."' AND c.clausula = cc.clausula AND c.tipo = cc.tipo");
}

public function store(Request $request, Contrato $contrato)
{
    ContratoClausula::where('contrato_id','=',$contrato->id)->delete();

    if (@$request->clausulas) {
        foreach ($request->clausulas as $row) {
            $clausulax = Clausula::find($row);

            $clausula = new ContratoClausula();

            $clausula->contrato_id = $contrato->id;
            $clausula->clausula = $clausulax->clausula;
            $clausula->tipo = $clausulax->tipo;

            $clausula->save();
```

Comment: Por favor si aparece algún error añadelo a tu pregunta, de paso considera editar y redactar un título que sea mas descriptivo del problema presentado

Comment: no me da error solo no carga los datos desde la tabla clausalas a la tabla contrato_clausulas

Comment: Asi como ayer comenté tu misma pregunta... ¿El `@` esta por de mas?

Comment: lo cambie y es lo mismo pana